# How to embed one variable value into another variable?

Tags: python

I would like to embed value of one variable into another variable as below but the below code doesn't work. Wondering how can it be done in Python. My variable x keeps changing dynamically and would like to have it as a separate value.

```
x = '1'

b = '''SELECT *
         FROM table 
        WHERE col1 IN ( CONCAT('abc',{{x}},'def%'), 
                        CONCAT('abc',{{x}},'ghi%') 
                       );
    '''
```

Comment: You must be using a library that handles SQL. Please read its documentation and let it handle variables in your queries, don't write custom queries with interpolated variables yourself. These easily lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: So you have a named string and a query. Where is your connection or cursor?

Comment: You could use `str.format` but for SQL using execution parameters is a better approach as @AndrasDeak mentioned already.

Answer (score -1):

The solution could be something like:

```
x = "1"
b = "SELECT * FROM TABLE.... 'abd{0}def%'\n'...abc{0}ghi%'".format(x)
```

for the remaining details Michael Butscher gave the important reference.